# Jquery - fix hyperlinks inside of a toggled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-propagation

I am having an issue with some Jquery script that I have and I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a region that is initially hidden but upon being clicked it displays it's contents, clicked again it hides it's contents.
Within this region are a series of hyperlinks. The trouble I am facing is that, when these links are clicked, instead of redirecting elsewhere the container is closing again. I can see why this is occurring but I am unsure how to fix it.

The Function:-

```
function toggleDisplay(itemToToggle, itemHeightOpen, itemHeightClosed) {
$(itemToToggle).toggle(
  function () {
    $(this).animate({ 'height': itemHeightClosed }).addClass('minus');
    },
      function () {
    $(this).animate({ 'height': itemHeightOpen }).removeClass('minus');
    });
 };
```

The Call:-

```
var heighttomatch = $('#inlineSummaryWrapper').height() + 28;
toggleDisplay('#inlineSummary', '1.2em', heighttomatch);
```

The html:-

```
<div id="inlineSummary" class="displayToggle">
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <div id="inlineSummaryWrapper">
   <a href="/mylink">the link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did try to wrap "The call" inside of a click action targeted at the H2 but that had a weird effect with the container opening and closing by itself, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `click` event on the link propagates. You can stop it with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

```
function toggleDisplay(itemToToggle, itemHeightOpen, itemHeightClosed) {
    $(itemToToggle).find('a').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome :) That's exactly the issue. Thanks for the help and thanks for teaching me something new today.